# Having difficulty finishing this time-based code snippet

Tags: javascript, methods

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

var button = document.querySelector(".button");

function myVarFunction() {
 setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function clockButton(document.querySelector(".button").toggle(".clockOn")){
 if(button.hasAttribute("class","clockOn")){
  clearInterval(myVar);
  }else{
 myVarFunction();
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="clockButton()" class = "button clockOn" >button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to execute a code snippet that will display the time in real-time (using the `setInterval()` method) and a `button` that when clicked will stop the time running in real-time, but if clicked again the time will run in real-time as it did before(using `.toggle()` to achieve this).

here is a link to the w3schools exercise where I got this idea from: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval

For some reason the time completely dissapears, none of my code works and I can't work out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Skip to the end if you just want the answer*

---

First thing's first, remove your `onClick` event from the HTML and place it in your script. This is the recommended way to set up events.

```
<button class="button clockOn">button</button>
```

and

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

var button = document.querySelector(".button");

// Add the event listener here
button.addEventListener("click", clockButton);
```

---

Now there's a couple of issues, but your most prominent one is the `clockButton` function. What you've got here is invalid JavaScript, you cannot execute code within the parameter list of a function:

```
function clockButton(document.querySelector(".button").toggle(".clockOn")){
  ...
}
```

You need to move this code to the body of the function instead.

```
function clockButton () {
  document.querySelector(".button").toggle(".clockOn");
  ...
}
```

That fixes the first problem, which is just invalid code. But the next problem you're going to face is that `toggle(...)` is not a function of the button element, (You may be confusing a bit of `jQuery` here, which has happened to me a number of times). You don't actually need this line of code though anyway, so you can remove it, and write your own class toggle.

It's fairly straightforward to write a class toggle, and you're actually doing a check already for the buttons class in your `if` statement, so it's a naturally obvious place for you to write the class toggle:

```
if(button.hasAttribute("class","clockOn")){
  ...
}
```

But unfortunately, there's a problem with the code above. Calling the `hasAttribute` function on an element will just check whether that attribute exists, not if it actually has a certain value. So in your case it will always be true, as you're never removing the class attribute, only changing it to something different.

To fix this up, you can use the `classList` functionality, which is the standard these days to deal with element classes in the native DOM API. You want to check that the element has the class `clockOn` so you can change the if statement to this:

```
if (button.classList.contains("clockOn")) {
  ...
}
```

To remove the class, you can use the `remove` function on the classlist like  so:

```
button.classList.remove("clockOn");
```

And you can add the class back using

```
button.classList.add("clockOn");
```

So all in all, your function becomes this

```
function clockButton(){
    if(button.classList.has("clockOn"){
        clearInterval(myVar);
        button.classList.remove("clockOn");
    }
    else {
        myVarFunction();
        button.classList.add("clockOn");
    }
}
```

Now that you're here, your button should work to stop the clock, and restart it again when you click it a second time, but it's not working properly yet, because you'll notice if you click it again, the time does not stop.

This is because `myVarFunction` does not reassign the new interval handle to the `myVar` variable. Every time you call `setInterval` you should get a new handle. So as an example, imagine that the first time you call `setInterval` it assigns the handle of `123`.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
// myVar === 123
```

Now `clearInterval(myVar)` will clear the running interval.

The next time you set the interval, it is within `myVarFunction`, lets say for example, it returns `456` the next time it's called.

```
function myVarFunction() {
   // setInterval returns `456`
   setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

   // myVar is still equal to `123`
}
```

The next time you try to clear the interval, you are clearing `123` (since you never reassigned the `myVar` variable) which doesn't exist, you should be clearing `456` which was the new interval you just set up.

So it's an easy fix

```
function myVarFunction() {
  myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}
```

---

**TL;DR**
Your code should look something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<!-- Remove the onclick event from here -->
<button class="button clockOn" >button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

var button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.addEventListener('click', clockButton);

function myVarFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function clockButton(){
    if(button.classList.contains("clockOn")){
        clearInterval(myVar);
        button.classList.remove("clockOn");
    }
    else {
        myVarFunction();
        button.classList.add("clockOn");
    }
}
```

See it live

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3ufcheg/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check my implementation below, the time continues from the current realtimee after toggling, I guess this is what you want.

```js
let time = document.getElementById("demo")
let myIntervalTimer;

function myStartFunction() {
 if(myIntervalTimer){
  clearInterval(myIntervalTimer)
 }
 myIntervalTimer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)
}

function myStopFunction() {
 clearInterval(myIntervalTimer)
}

function myTimer() {
  let d = new Date();
  let t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  time.innerHTML = t;
}

let timeClassList = time.classList
function toggleTime() {
if(timeClassList.contains('showTime')) {
 myStopFunction()
}
else {
  myStartFunction()
}
timeClassList.toggle("showTime")
}
myStartFunction()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo" class='showTime'></p>

<button onclick="toggleTime()">Toggle time</button>

</body>
</html>
```